# How to load local files in a WKWebView after downloading them (not in the bundle), and with params in the url?

Tags: ios, swift, url, wkwebview

I have tried to download files, and to load them in a WKWebView.
If I load them with and .html file it is okay, but when I want to indicate a param to go directly to a specific webpage, it doesn't load the page. It gives me a white page.

How to put params in the url and load it in the WKWebView?

```
    let url = Constants.Path.document + "/APP/index.html?180&2"
    let nsurl = URL(fileURLWithPath: url) //locally
    let readAccessToURL = nsurl.deletingLastPathComponent()
    webView?.loadFileURL(nsurl, allowingReadAccessTo: readAccessToURL)
```

(If I load it only with index.html, it works and if I use a UIWebView with the same url with params, it works)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with using `#` instead of `?` while preparing the `url`? One more thing - as I can see your resource is located on your device you may need to prefix `"file://"` before your full path. I was able to load with a pre-selected anchor following that. I tried with an `html` file in my `Bundle.main`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let weburl = "file://" + Bundle.main.path(forResource: "WebContent", ofType: "html")! + "#Lorem_Ipsum4"
        
        // Web view
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(webView!)
        
        webView!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        webView!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        webView!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        webView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        webView?.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: weburl)!))
    }
}
```

And this is my `WebContent.html`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
    .main-content {
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: justify;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="Lorem_Ipsum1">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p class="main-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
    </p>
    <h2 id="Lorem_Ipsum2">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p class="main-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
    </p>
    <h2 id="Lorem_Ipsum3">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p class="main-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
    </p>
    <h2 id="Lorem_Ipsum4">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p class="main-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
    </p>
    <p>Go to the
      <a href="#Lorem_Ipsum1">top</a>.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```